# What is the proper approach to get data with one to many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am following a tutorial in Django where I found a certain for loop to get the entities in a model which is actually filtering the data.

The below is the model (models.py)

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Model(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Review(models.Model):
    article = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    label_model = models.ManyToManyField(Model)
```

The below is the views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Brand
from .models import Model
from .models import Review

class BrandListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'phonereview/brands.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_phone_brands'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Brand.objects.all()

class ModelDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Brand
    template_name = 'phonereview/models.html'

class ReviewDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Model
    template_name = 'phonereview/reviews.html'
```

The below is the template
1) Listing brands (tempates/appname/brands.html)

```
<ul>
    {% for brand in all_phone_brands %}
        <li>
            <a href = "{% url 'phonereview:models' brand.slug %}">
                {{ brand.name }}
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Here the `all_phone_brands` is coming from views.py.
2) Template for listing phone models

```
<ul>
    {% for model_item in brand.model_set.all  %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'phonereview:reviews' model_item.slug %}">
            {{ model_item.model_name }}
        </a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Even though the code works, I am not sure putting `brand.model_set.all` is the proper approach. I guess, there must be a better approach then this.

Can anyone help me doing it in a proper way?

Answer (score 0):

Use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to optimize the query as,

```
Brand.objects.prefetch_related('model_set')
```

see the [documentation](http://Brand.objects.prefetch_related('model_set')) for more details.

Comment: how do I know its is ```model_set```? is it always in the form or ```{modelclass}_set``` and what if I have a model class named ```BookAuthor``` so in that case will it be ```bookauthor_set``` or ```bookAuthor_set```?

Comment: see the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward